# Экскурсия на/в почтовое отделение

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить "экскурсия на почтовое отделение" или "экскурсия в  почтовое отделение"? Или можно использовать оба варианта?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В почтовое отделение (в отделение почты), на почту.

Слово "отделение" может употребляться с предлогом "на" в значении *специализированного* отделения учреждения (напр., учебного: учиться на отделении хореографии, на вечернем отделении); для *территориальных* же "отделений" естественен предлог "в" (в какой части занимаемого пространства, в каком из отдельных помещений, филиалов).

Answer (score 1):

Экскурсия на почту, но экскурсия в почтовое отделение, хотя это один и тот же объект.

Если предмет мыслится (или просто представлен в названии) как  пространство, имеющее внутреннюю структуру, то используется предлог В (мы как бы заходим внутрь предмета), в противном случае используется предлог НА (в этом случае мы имеем дело с территориальным объектом).

Примеры:

Экскурсия на завод, на атомную электростанцию, на Соловки, на крейсер «Суворов».

Экскурсия в музей, в аквапарк, в горы, в пещеру, в архив, в Италию, в Третьяковскую галерею.

Comment: Экскурсия на Кубу(чем отличается от Италии?), на Филиппины, но в Индонезию(вообще никакой разницы, то и это государства, архипелаги), экскурсия на Цейлон, но в Бангладеш(старое и новое названия острова и страны), экскурсия на Урал, но в Карелию. И какие тут закономерности? Только не надо собственных воззрений, а что-нибудь академическое, желательно со ссылкой. И еще про В/НА Украину, а то братья наши меньшие очень обижаются и от обиды этой пишут теперь "на России" и "на Московии".